# Spring-WS: Converting SOAP Faults into Specific Exceptions

Tags: web-services, spring-ws

When using Spring-WS as a SOAP client, I have a hard time converting incoming faults to their specific Java Exceptions.

For example, if the web service operation I am calling can return a ClientNotFoundFault and let's say, an InvalidAmountFault, can I make Spring-WS throw either a ClientNotFoundException or an InvalidAmountException?

Can Spring-WS throw something different than SoapFaultClientException?

I can do this the other way around when writting the web service myself. There, using the SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver, I can easily convert Exceptions into their equivalent fault. I just couldn't find anything about doing it when writting the client...

I am using Spring-WS 2.1.0.RELEASE with JDK 1.7.6

Thanks and let me know if I am not clear enough or if you need some code example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent resolver on the client side.  The resolver interface is there all ready for someone to write a similar mapper.  Should be very straight forward to hold a map of fault codes vs exception classes.

See org.springframework.ws.client.core.FaultMessageResolver

This is implemented by SoapFaultMessageResolver at the moment which simply wraps the fault message in the SoapFaultClientException that you are seeing.